# Popup warning from IE9 in Sharepoint site, when ignored the site gets slow

Tags: jquery, performance, sharepoint, internet-explorer-9

We have a Sharepoint site with a template form bind.pt. Now, whenever I access the site I get a popup warning from IE9 which says that some content of the site will be blocked.

If I ignore the warning then I can browse through the site really fast. But when I accept the warning and show all content the site gets really slow. I started the debugger from IE and soon I found that https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js takes up to 9 seconds to finish loading.

Does anyone have any advice?

Comment: http instead of https usually loads faster.

Answer (score 0):

> http instead of https usually loads faster

Agreed.

Also, consider hosting that .js internally rather than through jquery.com